# How to get Cookies from response header in jMeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I am trying to get the cookies from a GET request when I first access a website via HTTP Request, there are a number of suggestions that suggest using user.properties files e.t.c. but I do not actually have these available as I am using the jMeter GUI to build the tests and it doesn't create these files.

Is there a way of getting the cookies from the header without the user.properties. Or if not, please could I request some detail as to how to achieve creating a user.properties file e.t.c. as I am very very new to jMeter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple caching you just need to add to Test Plan [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) and HTTP cookie(s) will be added.

user.properties is used for specific cases, and it is already exists in your JMeter bin folder in case you will need to update it.

Comment: Updated my answer